# Como colocar em ordem crescente os valores da escala discreta de Y?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quero criar um histograma no ggplot mas os valores do eixo y estão ficando fora de ordem. Quero coloca-los em ordem crescente no eixo. Tentei usar a função "reorder" mas não funcionou.

```
dados(hrlinear)
ID  Home range (m)
#MB02   156.148
#MB03   247.969
#MB04   156.148
#MB05   92.400
#MB06   1022.954
#MB07   156.148
#MB08   672.731
#MB09   156.148
#MB10   594.328
#MB11   554.670
#MB12   672.731
#MB13   474.969
#MB14   0.000
#MB15   0.000
#MB16   156.506
```

Estou usando o seguinte caminho:

```
ggplot(hrlinear,
 aes(x=ID, y = reorder(Home.range..m., -ID)))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity") +
 labs(x = "ID dos Tags", y = "Home range linear (m)")
```

Comment: Olá Francielle, o ideal é você colocar um ```dput()``` dos seus dados.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando os dados que colocou na pergunta:

> ```
> ID  Home range (m)
> #MB02   156.148
> #MB03   247.969
> #MB04   156.148
> #MB05   92.400
> #MB06   1022.954
> #MB07   156.148
> #MB08   672.731
> #MB09   156.148
> #MB10   594.328
> #MB11   554.670
> #MB12   672.731
> #MB13   474.969
> #MB14   0.000
> #MB15   0.000
> #MB16   156.506
> ```

Criando o data.frame:

```
v1 <- c('MB02','MB03','MB04','MB05','MB06','MB07',
        'MB08','MB09','MB10','MB11','MB12','MB13',
        'MB14','MB15','MB16')

v2 <- c(156.148, 247.969,156.148,92.400,1022.954,156.148,
        672.731,156.148,594.328,554.670,672.731,474.969,
        0.000,0.000,156.506)

dados <- data.frame(v1,v2)
```

**Decrescente**

Você pode utilizar sim o reorder em x:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dados, aes(x = reorder(v1, -v2), y = v2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "ID dos Tags", y = "Home range linear (m)")
```

Saída:

[image: histogram]

---

Edit

**Crescente**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dados, aes(x = reorder(v1, v2), y = v2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "ID dos Tags", y = "Home range linear (m)")
```

Saída:

[image: hist - crescente]

Comment: Voto a favor mas `as.data.frame(cbind(v1,v2))` é de evitar, o `cbind` cria uma matrix e portanto transforma tudo em `character`. `data.frame(v1, v2)` cria logo um data.frame mantendo as classes dos vetores. E além de ser mais simples, não precisa do `as.numeric(as.character(dados$v2))` seguinte.

Comment: Verdade! Havia utilizado as.data.frame, dai exibe um erro, nem me antenei. Vou atualizar o código! Abraço!

Comment: Obrigada pessoal, mas não quero que as colunas do histograma fiquem em ordem decrescente. eu quero colocar os valores do eixo Y em ordem crescente, pq quando gero o gráfico com o meu código, o valor do MB05 fica sendo o maior ao invés do MB06